# Does the Canis Major Dwarf Galaxy have a black hole at its centre?

Tags: black-hole, observational-astronomy, galactic-center, dwarf-galaxy

I am just wondering: is there a potential galactic centre out there that's very close to us? I know that CMDG is irregular, but can it still contain a black hole at the centre?

Comment: Do you mean a supermassive black hole, or just a regular one?

Comment: @probably_someone Well, I'd hope for a supermassive one - so that it can serve as a 'gravitational centre' to the Galaxy - but even if a regular one exists so that it's the centre to the galaxy, that would still answer my question.

Comment: I'm under the impression that even the existence of the CMDG is a source of minor controversy.  If it exists (as a galaxy) it will be irregular and I'm not sure the word "center" applies here.

Comment: @StephenG Yes, as I mentioned, I do appreciate that if it ever is a galaxy, it is irregular; however, even such irregular galaxies, I believe, contain smaller groups of star clusters which may all be centred around an older black hole. Of course, that would not technically be a 'galactic centre', but that would still be pretty cool.

Comment: Just to note: even supermassive black holes are only small fractions of the mass of a galaxy, even a dwarf galaxy. The bodies within the galaxy orbit, overall, each other - their center of gravity, that is.

Comment: ‘even if a regular one exists so that it's the centre to the galaxy’ makes no sense. A “regular” stellar BH has the same mass as a “regular” star, and there’s plenty of these at the centre of any galaxy. In any case, a stellar BH in CMDG would be exceedingly hard to detect.